# Can the monsters in A Quiet Place swim?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-quiet-place, a-quiet-place-2

In *A Quiet Place 2* it is explicitly stated that early in the invasion people realized that the monsters can't swim.  And this is a key plot point explaining the safety of an island located within close view of the mainland.

But on at least two occasions we see the monsters intentionally diving into and under the water:

1. In *A Quiet Place*, in the flooded basement, Evelyn watches as one slips under the water towards her.  In this case the water is only a few feet deep so the monster could have easily waded, but instead chose to submerge itself.
2. In *A Quiet Place 2* one dives off the dock towards Regan.

In both cases I thought, "Uh oh."  Since they are sound-guided predators I expected they would have a bigger advantage underwater.  (Their clicking is eerily similar to the clicks dolphins use to search and hunt underwater.)

In neither of these cases do we get to see what the monster does after submerging.  But the monsters seem comfortable and familiar with water: they streamline by tucking their forearms against their body and enter head-first, similar to the way diving and swimming birds do.

So is there any evidence that the monsters are impaired underwater?  Or any in-universe support for the statement that the monsters *can't* swim?  Or is it not that they *can't* but rather that (to that point) nobody had observed them *choosing* to swim any distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the moment in the first movie where a monster slowly and intentionally slips under the shallow water in the flooding basement:

If it were impaired underwater there would be no reason to do this, since it could easily have kept its head above the water.  This suggests they do have some sensory or tactical advantage underwater.

However, here is the second movie where a monster jumps from a boat into the water just off the dock:

As the scene continues, the monster thrashes its limbs wildly as if drowning and quickly claws its way back onto the boat instead of pursuing the people in the water.

Based on these two scenes we can conclude that while the monsters can submerge, **they can't swim** and they avoid water so deep that they can't touch bottom.